Why this query is failing? It looks logically correct as per the SOQL documentation

SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD) FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'ClosedWon'
AND CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate) = CALENDAR_MONTH(TODAY) AND
CALENDAR_YEAR(CloseDate) = CALENDAR_YEAR(TODAY)


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail - are you getting an error?

As per the documentation, You can't compare the result of a date function with a date literal in a WHERE clause.
You can use THIS_MONTH Date Literal will return the data based on the current month.
Query:

SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD)  FROM Opportunity  WHERE StageName = 'Closed
Won'  AND CloseDate = THIS_MONTH

